# Access root parent directory on Chromebook from different computer

Tags: linux, bash, macbook-pro, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I am trying to access all of the files on my Chromebook from a different computer.

From the Chromebook, I can access all of the local files that I have created or downloaded, just not the ones that I might need for developmental purposes, such as System files.

I understand that putting my Chromebook in developer mode I could do this with crosh, but I do not want to wipe my hard drive, because I want to keep the files that I have, which includes the root files on the Chromebook that I cannot access.

If I were to take apart the Chromebook and access the motherboard, would I be able to access those files (including the root ones) from my MacBook Pro? Or could I just plug in my Chromebook to my Mac? Could I set up some sort of file share?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Allowing access to system files from a remote system has very serious security implications. I can see why it would be necessary to put a system into Dev mode to allow this, and I would bet that what you are wanting to do is impossible with a system not in Dev mode.

Comment: @music2myear despite any security implications, how would you access system files from a remote system?

Comment: I don't think you understood what I was saying: Because of the security implications, my bet is that Google has built their system so as not to allow what you're asking, apart from the Dev mode method which you mentioned you were already aware of and was not the right solution for you.

Comment: @music2myear ah ok, i understand you now. thanks for your response.